# How to report by page type in Universal Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, universal-analytics

I currently log type of the page in custom variable like this:

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'PageCategory', 'Product', 3]);
```

With the following options:

- Home page
- List
- Login page
- etc.

After upgrading to Universal Analytics I want to be able to use page category as attribute in reports.

Is it something supported by existing API or I need to create a new dimension?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a new custom dimension:

[image]

Then pass your old value into the new snippet:

```
ga('set', 'dimension1', 'Product');
```

Comment: +1 but it might be better to use content groupings (which do not necessarily need code plus they might save a precious custom dimension).